# Angular error TS2564 Property 'formGroup' has no initializer

Tags: angular, typescript, formgroups

```
  formGroup: FormGroup;
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

  createForm() {
    this.formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      'username': ['', Validators.required],
      'password': ['', Validators.required],
    });
  }


  getError(el) {
    switch (el) {
      case 'user':
        if (this.formGroup.get('username').hasError('required')) {
          return 'login is required';
        }
        break;
      case 'pass':
        if (this.formGroup.get('password').hasError('required')) {
          return 'password is required';
        }
        break;
      default:
        return '';
    }
  }
```

login angualr app

error TS2564: Property 'formGroup' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.

how do i fix it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is something related to the strict initialization.

1. **Add ! to aware this is not initialized**:

```
formGroup!: FormGroup;
```

2. **Add |undefined as additional type** :

```
formGroup: FormGroup | undefined
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use non-null assertion operator to prevent the type checker from throwing error

```
 formGroup!: FormGroup;
```

**Or**

Move all the formGroup intialization to top level

```
  formGroup = this.formBuilder.group({
      'username': ['', Validators.required],
      'password': ['', Validators.required],
  });
   
  constructor(private formBuilder: FormBuilder) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
```